# How does Feature importances with forests of trees work?

Tags: python, tree, feature-selection

Can anyone explain how use of forests of trees to evaluate the importance of features (feature_importances_) works?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a random Forest Implementation. Random forest consists of a number of decision trees. Every node in the decision trees is a condition on a single feature, designed to split the dataset into two so that similar response values end up in the same set. The measure based on which the (locally) optimal condition is chosen is called impurity. For classification, it is typically either Gini impurity or information gain/entropy and for regression trees it is variance. Thus when training a tree, it can be computed how much each feature decreases the weighted impurity in a tree. For a forest, the impurity decrease from each feature can be averaged and the features are ranked according to this measure.